# Java allow Upper and Lower cases

Tags: java, string

Using `java.util.Scanner;` I want the console to allow the users to input from upper and lower cases. For example:

```
if (user.equals("test") {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

But I want the console to accept all type of cases, so the user can input like `TEST` and maybe `TeSt` and the console would see that as "test"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with:

```
if ("test".equalsIgnoreCase(user)) { 
    System.out.println("hello"); 
}
```

Note that I'm applying the [`String#equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) method on `"test"`, but not on the `user` variable, in order to avoid a possible `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`:

```
if( user.equalsIgnoreCase("test") ) {
    ...
}
```

As the name implies,

```
x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)
```

returns true if `x` and `y` are two strings who are equal, ignoring upper and lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
Use  `object.equalIgnoreCase(object2)`
Method 2:
Convert user input into lowercase and then compare
for example like below
`user=user.toLowercase();`
`user.equal("hello");`